# Azure DevOps: Pipeline with Powershell using "git clone" not working

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Having the following error:

> remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier MyRepo does
> not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are
> attempting. fatal: repository
> 'https://dev.azure.com/MyCompany/MyProject/_git/MyRepo/' not found

Pipeline:

```
stages:
 - stage: "Stage1"
   jobs:
    - job: MyJob
      displayName: 'MyJob'
      pool: 'MyWindowsSrv'
      steps:
      - checkout: self
        persistCredentials: true

      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: Some name...
        env:
          SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
        name: some_name
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $path = "C:\MyRepo"
            If(!(test-path -PathType container $path))
            {
                    Set-Location C:\ -PassThru
                    Git clone https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/MyCompany/MyProject/_git/MyRepo
            }
            Set-Location $path -PassThru
            Git pull
          failOnStderr: true
          showWarnings: true
          workingDirectory:  $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

As you can see, I have also set the security settings:
[image: Security Settings in Repository]

Any ideas?

Comment: In general, you'll want to avoid writing the Git binary as `Git`.  While that may happen to work on Windows, it absolutely will not work on Unix or under WSL.

Comment: Why are you trying to check out a repository via the CLI instead of adding a `repository` resource and using the standard `checkout` task?

Comment: Did the answer posted on the ticket help you? If it helps. just as a remind of [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks for your kindness :-)

Comment: @EvelynChen-MSFT yes, thank you. I will use a different approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that there are two service accounts, one is the collection level account (Project Collection Build Service (xxxxx)) and another is project level account ({ProjectName} Build Service (xxx) ). If you have enabled the
**Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines** setting, you are using the project level account. Please make sure the corresponding build service account has the required permission.

At the same time, please check if you have enabled **Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines**.

> With this option enabled, you can reduce the scope of access for all
> pipelines to only Azure DevOps repositories explicitly referenced by a
> checkout step or a uses statement in the pipeline job that uses that
> repository.

If you do, you could try disabling the setting **Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines** in Project settings->Pipelines->Settings to see if it works.
[image] For your reference, you could find more details in this official doc: [Access repositories, artifacts, and other resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#protect-access-to-repositories-in-yaml-pipelines).

By the way, you could also click the button **Gnerate Git Credential** when you trying to clone the repo.
[image]

And use the username and the password in the following script to clone the repo:

```
git clone https://username:password@dev.azure.com/MyOrganization/MyProject/_git/MyRepoName
```

And you could also consider simply using the [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines) step.

If you want to checkout multiple repositories, you could consider following the steps in this official doc: [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops).

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository
    type: git
    name: OtherProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: MyAzureReposGitRepository
```